# Android AlarmManager WAKEUP

Tags: android

I use the code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        0, 60000, alarmIntent);
```

How long will the phone to stay awake after the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely on any information from this point of view. If your pending intent is for a broadcast receiver, you should use a wakefulBroadcastReceiver ([doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)) taking your own wakelock, start an intent service for example and release the lock.

Comment: And if I do not put a lock awake? How long the device is asleep?

Comment: As I said it's completely not deterministic. There isn't a specific time.

Comment: I'm on the phone: sleep mode after 2 minutes of inactivity. Does it matter?

Comment: No they are two different things

Comment: Can you say, how do they differ?

Comment: You are talking about the timer after screen on due to user interaction. In this case we are talking about the wake of the cpu during possible deep sleep period.